# Any way in JavaScript to avoid using setTimeout to execute a function right after another? Maybe with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code:

```
$newFilter = getNewFilter();

$fieldDropdown = getFieldDropdown(fieldData.field);
$newFilter.append($fieldDropdown);

$typeDropdown = getTypeDropdown($fieldDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId, $fieldDropdown.val(), fieldData.type);
$newFilter.append($typeDropdown);

$inputBox = getInputBox($typeDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId, $typeDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldType, $typeDropdown.val(), fieldData.value);
$newFilter.append($inputBox);
```

And I get a error (`$fieldDropdown.data("zenfilter") is null`) on the fourth line (`$typeDropdown = getTypeDropdown...`). This is because the `getFieldDropdown` didn't finished execution yet. How can I call the functions lineally? Thanks a lot.

Edit: Added the getFieldDropdown function:

```
getFieldDropdown = function (populateData) {
    var $hiddenInput, i, $obj;

    $hiddenInput = $('<input>', {
        name: defaults.paramName + '[' + nFilters + '][field]',
        type: 'hidden'
    });
    $obj = $('<select></select>', {
        'class': classesHash.individualField,
        name: defaults.paramName + '[' + nFilters + '][fakefield]'
    }).
    data('zenfilter', { fieldId: nFilters }).
    addOption(fieldOptions).
    sortOptions(true).
    selectOptions('').
    change(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('select, div.' + classesHash.individualInputContainer).detach();
        $(this).removeClass(classesHash.incompleteField).after(getTypeDropdown($(this).data('zenfilter').fieldId, $(this).val()));
        $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val(defaults.data[$(this).val()].fieldname);
    });
    if (populateData) {
        for (i = 0; i < defaults.data.length; i += 1) {
            if (defaults.data[i].fieldname === populateData) {
                $obj.selectOptions(String(i));
            }
        }
    }

    return $hiddenInput.add($obj);
};
```

(addOptions, sortOptions and selectOptions are just a plugin's methods to manipulate selects easier, they don't do any AJAX)

Comment: does `getFieldDropdown` make an AJAX call to load the data?

Comment: Are you positive this is what is happening here? Where is $typeDropdown.data('zenfilter') set? Does the getFieldDropdown call execute an AJAX query, subsequently setting the data for the $typeDropdown. Otherwise I would say everything above would execute synchronously, and sequentially.

Comment: We need the function definition for getFieldDropdown to see if it is asynchronous, or most likely, synchronous (in which case a timer wouldn't help at all).

Comment: You're giving a question with so many unknowns that it becomes guess work to give you a solution to your case - that's not very effective...

Comment: @steve_c: $typeDropdown.data('zenfilter') is set inside getTypeDropdown(). There are no AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those functions *are* called synchronously. What's most likely happening is that `getFieldDropdown(fieldData.field)` is returning null, or the object that it returns doesn't have the `zenfilter` property defined internally.

Comment: You were right, Daniel, ($fieldDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId was null. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `getFieldDropdown` is an asynchronous call, from your question (a definition for that function would make this question easier to answer).

JavaScript does execute in a single-threaded way; your problem is not that `getFieldDropdown` doesn't complete, your problem is that it initiates an asynchronous call and then returns.  If you want to do work with the results of an asynchronous call, you have to provide that call a callback:  a function to execute when it's done.

Assuming the callback is the second, currently un-provided argument to getFieldDropdown, you'd do something like this:

```
$fieldDropdown = getFieldDropdown(fieldData.field, function(){
    $newFilter.append($fieldDropdown);

    $typeDropdown = getTypeDropdown($fieldDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId,$fieldDropdown.val(), fieldData.type);
    $newFilter.append($typeDropdown);

    $inputBox = getInputBox($typeDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId,$typeDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldType, $typeDropdown.val(), fieldData.value);
    $newFilter.append($inputBox);
});
```

that lets you defer the execution of the stuff that relies on the results of the asynchronous call until those results are there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit getFieldDropdown in order to achieve this. Instead of making it execute serially, it is better to re-design so that it can accept a callback method to run when execution is finished. This is the standard way with jQuery:

```
fieldDropdown = getFieldDropdown(fieldData.field, function () {

  $newFilter.append($fieldDropdown);

  $typeDropdown = getTypeDropdown($fieldDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId,   $fieldDropdown.val(), fieldData.type);
  $newFilter.append($typeDropdown);

  $inputBox = getInputBox($typeDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldId,   $typeDropdown.data('zenfilter').fieldType, $typeDropdown.val(), fieldData.value);
  $newFilter.append($inputBox);

}
);
```